# Correlation between X and Y from likert scale

Tags: correlation, likert

I have a question regarding Pearson correlation analysis, I have two data that I have conducted from a questionnaire, I measured the data using likert scale, the data that I supposed to find is the correlation between height and self esteem, but I still confuse as to how to process the questionnaire data for self esteem which is the data of likert scale, height is for example as X with self esteem as Y, do I have to sum the score of the questions per person so I can decide the Y?

Comment: Yes, the individual questions will be summed or averaged to create a _scale_. If this is an established scale, be careful to sum questions with the correct order of responses.  That is, sometimes scales are set up with some questions having 5 being the highest and some questions with 5 being the lowest.  If this is not an established scale, usually a measure of "reliability" like Chronbach's alpha is used to determine how consistent the scale is.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already did as you said, Thank you :)